# Android - Domain Entity Mapper

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using clean architecture pattern in my application, i have domain entities in **domain** layer, where i will be using these entities in both **data** and **app** layer, yeah its fine, but my problem is when i want to share any entity between activities in my app layer i need to bundle this with either **serializable** or **parcealizable**, but according to documentation serializable performance is less when compared to parcealizable, so i decided to use parcealizable in my entities, since the domain is full of kotlin module i am not able to use  android dependencies.
How can i achieve this using parcealizable in domain module ?
Any help

Comment: Use [@Parcelize](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html?_ga=2.212500500.1243136674.1556277380-241970380.1543409870#parcelable-implementations-generator) annotation.

Comment: You should not use domain classes in the app layer, you should have a data and app layers which contains the "same" models (or similar to entities) but not the same, as you want them to be separated